# Specifying POST in rails 3 routes and calling from Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails for my backend to a Flash app. I need to send a bunch of params to rails from flash using post. I have a rails action in my users_controller called register

my routes file looks like this

```
  resources :users

  match 'register'  => 'Users#register', :via => :post
```

the actionscript looks something like this

```
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
vars.first_name = "First";
vars.last_name = "Last";
vars.address = "555 Mysteet Rd.";
vars.email = "me@example.com";
vars.city = "The Hill";
vars.provice = "KY";
vars.postal_code = "55555";

var request : URLRequest = new URLRequest("/register");
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.data = vars;

var loader : URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, registerHandler);
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
loader.load(request);
```

The error I am getting in Flash is an IO_ERROR Streaming Event bla bla bla witch usually indicates that the URL you are calling does not exist. If I change the request.method to GET then the call works but not all the data gets sent to rails because GET can't handle the length of the data being sent.

Comment: For debugging, to see exactly what is POSTed from Flash, and the response that is sent back (also if it is an error page, possibly with debug info), i recommend http://www.charlesproxy.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does your controller and action look like?

For API type calls, such as from Flash/Flash to Rails, I don't use custom routings. Rather I rely on RESTful actions. So I'm calling:

/users/create/

Since you declared your resource for :users in your routes, you should have this routing in place (assuming you have a RESTful create action).

Gimme me details and I'll try to help more.

[edit]

More details from Matt via IM:

- controller is Users and action is Register
- POST is successfully received in Rails, but throws the error

  ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

For security Rails 3 adds a hidden form field with a token that is expected with any POST to a Rails controller. Because this POST is occurring from Flash, this token is obviously missing and we get this error.

To fix the issue, disable the authenticity check for the controller with:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

Comment: totally did the trick and thanks again for hopping on IM with me dude.

Comment: First off, you need to do some **before filter** work:

`skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:your_action]
before_filter :semi_verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:your_action]`
Then you need a function to define when to check for the token authenticity:

`def semi_verify_authenticity_token
  verify_authenticity_token unless request.xhr? # Or whatever other criteria you would use
end`
Info quoted from [here](http://www.patricktulskie.com/2010/04/skip-rails-authenticitytoken-check-sometimes/)